# How to duplicate/clone a Linux-VM in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to duplicate a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) virtual machine in Microsoft Azure. The only idea I have is cloning the blob storage, creating a new VM and mount the blob storage but I cannot make it work.

Is there a better way to get a running clone? Any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There is some great information on how to use your current Linux VM to create a template for spinning up multiple copies of your VM configuration.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/

Your scenario would be two steps:
    Create your VM template
    Create your second VM using the template in your RM Template.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to mount the whole blob.. If you're using the Classic Model of creating VMs, all you have to do is go to your VM, Capture an Image of it, and then go to New --> Create VMs from Templates and on your lower left you'll see Images, select it and then choose the image you just captured and that's it!